# Multiple If with Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a little problem with if and regex and don't found my mistake :-(

On submit i have a each to loop through all input fields (works)

Then a have a if on all input fields where is "von" in the name.

The first part if there no chars in it works great (standalone) the other with the regex doesn't work :-(

So the if should be run when nothing is in the field and when the format doesn't meets the 24h time format 00:00 or 09:30 ...

So the red border should be visible when there is nothing in the field and when the input doesn't meets the 24h time format.

Now it runs every time with the right and the false input :-(

The Code:

```
$(submit1).click(function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var regtime = /([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;

    $("input").css({"border": "1px solid #bbb"});

    $("input").each(function(index) {

        if($('input[name$="[von]"]').val() == '' || (!regtime.test($('input[name$="[von]"]'))))
        {
            $('input[name$="[von]"]').css({"border": "solid", "border-color": "red"});
        }
    });
});
```

THANK YOU !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var valid = true;
//loop through only the desired input fields
$('input[name$="[von]"]').each(function () {
    //get the value of the current input fields in the loop
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val();
    //target the value in the regex
    if (value == '' || !regtime.test(value)) {
        $this.css({
            "border": "solid",
                "border-color": "red"
        });
        valid = false;
    }
});

if (!valid) {
    //prevent form submit
}
```

Since TJ deleted the answer, borrowing his explanation for the regex test failure

> Passing a jQuery object into RegExp#test will implicitly call toString
>   on it, and so the value you'd test would be "[object Object]" rather
>   than the value of the input.

Comment: a little addition required though; it seems that the border should be red if an input is empty or wrong. And if not, back to default. You have to add an `else` block with `$("input").css({"border": "1px solid #bbb"});`

Comment: @KarelG I think `$("input").css({"border": "1px solid #bbb"});` resets all the input fields to the default border

Comment: yeah, it seems a validation function to me. That's why i thought to add it ... not sure.

Comment: I missed the .val() so it dont checked the value :-( ... Thanks also for the expenation an loop on an specific field but i have to validate nearly all fields (one ist not validated) so i tink its better to loop throgh all with a secound if for the fields and do error handling with something like valerror = 1 or valerror = 0 to prevent the post from submit if there is an error ?